# SSIS Execute SQL not returning result

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Using a Execute SQL Task to find if any records were loaded during a ETL. For some reason Record count is always 0. The batch_Id is correct as you can see in the watch window. I have tried everything I can think of. Including making batchid a parameter and using ? in the query. Using a ADO Data source. If I take the query and execute it on my server it returns a record count, so I know there are records. The execution results doesn't show any errors. I have tried everting I can think of. Please help. Thank you in advance.

It would be easy to test just create a table 'Trace_Return_BRE' with a few records with one field "Batchid" = '2102010900'

Task: Get record Count
Conn Type: OLE DB
Conn: SQLServer
SQL Source: Direct Input

SQL Statement (from Expression)

```
DECLARE @BatchId as VARCHAR(10) 

SET @BatchId = '2102010900'

SELECT COUNT(*) As RecCnt 
FROM  dbo.Trace_Return_BRE 
WHERE (BatchId = @BatchId)
```

Parameter Mapping: None
Result Name : 0
Variable Name : User::RecordCount 
Expression: SQLStatmentSource

> "DECLARE @BatchId as VARCHAR(10)
> SET @BatchId = '" +
> @[User::Batch_Id] + "'
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) As RecCnt  FROM  dbo.Trace_Return_BRE  WHERE (BatchId
> = @BatchId)"

---

ETL Variable
User::Batch_ID String = 2102010900

[image]

Comment: Don't se the Jpeg with screen shot

Comment: On the General tab of your Execute SQL task, do you have the ResultSet configuration set to "Single row" or "Full result set"?

Comment: Check this article, it might help [Execute SQL Task in SSIS: Output Parameters vs Result Sets](https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-tasks-in-ssis-output-parameters-vs-result-sets/)

Comment: Thanks it is working now